# How to auto focus on first input field using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 20 html pages in my project I need to implement a common angular code directive to auto focus on the first input field on all pages.

Comment: you can try using the `autofocus` attribute on the input itself

Comment: @Ronnie the main problem is i cannot make the changes in html code.

Comment: what an unfortunate problem. So technically the answer below won't work either.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
angular.module('utils.autofocus', [])

.directive('autofocus', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link : function($scope, $element) {
      $timeout(function() {
        $element[0].focus();
      });
    }
   }
}]);

// <input type="text" autofocus>
```

You could also try [ng-autofocus](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-autofocus)